# Python MongoDB Multiple Database Design Query

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, database, nosql

I was hoping someone with more in-depth knowledge of MongoDB could provide some feedback on the implementation for my database requirements.

I am currently implementing a web application using Flask and MongoDB for my client who's business has multiple physical locations. They, as the Managing Director, want to be able to access information for each of the locations individually but they want to restrict the managers of each location to just their information.

I can envisage two different solutions to this but am not familiar enough with the underlying technology/design of MongoDB to fully appreciate the pros and cons of each implementation.

For each solution I have a user model that contains which location(s) a user has access to.

Solution 1 would involve each document having a field to record which location the object belonged to and then including that as a filter in every query. This seems the simplest to implement but would result in a single large database, could there be scaling issues?

Solution 2 involves having a separate user database, and an individual database for each location. When a request is made the application would have to establish from the user database which location they are accessing and connect to that database. This at first appears more complex to implement but would result in smaller isolated databases which may make it easier to scale but possibly harder to manage.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback on my solutions or any other solutions I have not considered.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Whoops, good spot! Yes MongoDB.